# Apache POI Generate large xlsx file with SXSSF

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi, xlsx

I'm trying to generate a large report on xslx format using Apache POI. I was using XSSF to generate correctly xslx file but suddently got memory error.

To avoid out of memory exception I tried to change to SXSSF like this.

```
// Create results Sheet
SXSSFWorkbook workBook = new SXSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet xssfSheet = (XSSFSheet) workbook.createSheet(name);
PrintSetup printSetup = xssfSheet.getPrintSetup();
printSetup.setLandscape(true);
xssfSheet.setFitToPage(true);
xssfSheet.setHorizontallyCenter(true);
```

But i got this error

```
10:56:46,023 ERROR [stderr] (default task-47) java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFSheet cannot be cast to org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet
```

My problem is that there is not way to workbook.createSheet(name) returns me an instance of XSSFSheet to do my work.

There is a way to cast SXSSF to XSSF ??

Comment: Why not using [SXSSFSheet](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFSheet.html)?

Comment: I was trying to avoid that because I have like 5 large excel reports on my site and I dont want to rewrite them all ... but i think this is the correct solution. I can do find and replace. Thanks :)